# D3 getting JSON data within a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Using [this as reference.](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642#index.html) I am trying to implement this into my page. However, the JSON data that I am using has JSON within it. 
  So my JSON looks similar to this:

```
{
"nodes": [
{"fixed":true,"classes": null,"data": {"id": "imombr","idType":"USERNAME","visible":true },"grabbable": true,"grabbed":false,"group":null,"locked": false,"position":null},
{"fixed":true,"classes": null,"data": {"id": "stephieru_","idType":"USERNAME","visible":true },"grabbable": true,"grabbed":false,"group":null,"locked": false,"position":null}
],
"links": [
    {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}
]
}
```

So I am trying to get the id within data as my text display. I have tried several things but it seems like I can't reach within to get id. Attempted:

```
node.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.data[id] });
```

and

```
node.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.data[0] });
```

but neither seems to work.

Comment: have you also tried `d.data.id`? if that doesn't work, try just printing out `d` and seeing that you get the proper obj.

Comment: boombox you were right. I am a fool.

Comment: You are far from a fool, Joey. Don't worry. The good news is I don't think you'll make this mistake again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `d.data[id]` use `d.data['id']` or, as boombox suggests, `d.data.id`